# Similar result to a property of power series by P. Erdos et al

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, power-series, formal-power-series

The following theorem is from ["A property of power series with positive coefficients" by P. Erdos et al](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-55/issue-2/A-property-of-power-series-with-positive-coefficients/bams/1183513498.full).

Let $p_k$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers for which $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_k=1$ and let $m=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp_k\le\infty$. If $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_kx^{k}$ is not a power series in $x^t$ for any integer $t>1$, then the series
$$
U(x)=\frac{1}{1-P(x)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u_kx^{k}
$$
has the property $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=1/m$.

Actually, the theorem could be used to study the limit of a sequence $u_n$ with $u_0=1$, $u_n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_jp_{n-j}=1$.

I was wondering if there is a similar result that could be  used to study the limit behaviour if $u_n$ satisfies the following condition:

$u_0=1$, $b_{k,0}=1$ for each $k\ge0$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{k}u_{j}b_{j,k-j}=1$ where each $0<b_{j,k-j}<1$. Any hint, reference or suggestion would be of great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $m$? It first appears in the sentence "has the property $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=1/m$.", but it is not defined anywhere...

Comment: Sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: $m=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp_k$